# The script works only once by clicking on the opening and closing

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

What is wrong with my code? What needs to be fixed so that the script always works on clicks of buttons?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Выполнить асинхронный Ajax-запрос с помощью метода POST.
// Отправить данные на сервер и в случае успеха вывести 
// ответ сервера в диалоговом окне.
jQuery(document).die('click', '.sale_buton')  
jQuery(document).on('click', '.sale_buton', function(event) {
jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // сделали запрос 
                    type: "POST", // указали метод
                    data: { // передаем параметры отправляемого запроса
                        action: 'my_ajax_action', // вызываем хук который обработает наш ajax запрос
                        price: jQuery(this).data('price'), // передаем параметры из кнопки 
                        user: jQuery(this).data('user'), // передаем параметры из кнопки 
                    },
   success: function(data){
     jQuery('.results').html( /*"ИНФОРМАЦИЯ О СРАЖЕНИИ:<br>" + */data );
}
 })
return false;
/* as before */ });

jQuery(document).on('click', '.close', function() { 
jQuery('.results').remove();
return false;
/* as before */ });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, here is my solution code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Выполнить асинхронный Ajax-запрос с помощью метода POST.
    // Отправить данные на сервер и в случае успеха вывести 
    // ответ сервера в диалоговом окне.
    //jQuery(document).die('click', '#order_'+button.id) ; 

    function showPopup (button) {
        jQuery(document).on('click', '#'+button.id, function(event) {
        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // сделали запрос 
                            type: "POST", // указали метод
                            data: { // передаем параметры отправляемого запроса
                                action: 'my_ajax_action', // вызываем хук который обработает наш ajax запрос
                                orderid: jQuery(this).data('orderid'), // передаем параметры из кнопки 
                                user: jQuery(this).data('user'), // передаем параметры из кнопки 
                            },
           success: function(data)

           {
             jQuery('.results').html( /*"ИНФОРМАЦИЯ О СРАЖЕНИИ:<br>" + */data );
             jQuery('.results').show();
          }
         })
        return false;
         /* as before */ 
        });
    };
     function closePopup (button_id) {

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#close_'+button_id, function() { 
    jQuery('.results').hide();
    return false;
    /* as before */ });
    }
    </script>
```

And here is this piece of code in the front-end (this is just part of the code in php file - sorry, but I can’t show the whole file):

```
    echo '<td style="text-align: center;border-left: none;font-size: 17px;"><button onclick="javascript:showPopup(this);" class="sale_buton checkout-button button alt wc-forward" id="order_'.$lineItem['order_id'].'" data-orderid="'.$lineItem['order_id'].'" data-user="'.$user_id.'" data-variation="'.$lineItem['variation_id'].'" href="">Сразиться</button></td></tr>';// /*'. esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ) .'*/Кнопка отрабатывает по клику - выхватывает Ajax-ом такие данные как (id участника-заявителя, название заявки, id заявки, ставка-взнос-тариф)'</td>';     
        } 
    }         
    echo '</tbody></table></br>' ;
    ?>
<div class="results"></div> <!-- здесь будет выводится результат -->
```

And this is part of the code that I put into the function.php file in the plugin (I also can’t show the code - only the part that is responsible for working with JS):

```
add_action("wp_ajax_my_ajax_action", "k_ajax_my_ajax_action");// для фронтенда 
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_action", "k_ajax_my_ajax_action");// для админки


function k_ajax_my_ajax_action(){
echo '<div class="clos">';
echo '<div class="close" id="close_'.$_POST['orderid'].'" onclick="javascript:closePopup('.$_POST['orderid'].');">Закрыть</div></br>';
//here is some code that can be executed
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="cl"></div>';
exit; 

}
```

And CSS:

```
    .cl {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 1px;
        left: 1px;
        background: black;
        opacity: 0.8;
        z-index: 1030;
    }

    .clos {
        width: 360px;
        height: auto;
        background: white;
        top: 80px;
        z-index: 1031;
        padding: 1%;
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
    }
.close{
float:right;
font-size:21px;
font-weight:700;
line-height:1;
color:#000;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;opacity:.2;
filter:alpha(opacity=20)
}
      .close:hover,.close:focus{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
cursor:pointer;
opacity:.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50)
}
      button.close{
padding:0;
cursor:pointer;
background:0 0;
border:0;-webkit-appearance:none
}
```

And here is a living example: **[svary.club](https://svary.club/zayavka-na-uchastie/)**